# jquery ui tooltip items option not working

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

It seems for some reason the items option here doesn't work. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but can't get the error. Can you help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>test jquery</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".div1").tooltip({ items: 'img[alt]'});
    }); 

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="div1">
    <img src="home-slider-next-button.png" width="26" height="24" alt="test2">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I took a closer look at the tooltip code and see that it seems it doesn't really take the alt attribute for content. It only uses items content as a selector. So my solution, for now, is to use the content option like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".div1").tooltip({ items: 'img[alt]', content:function(){ return $(this).attr('alt'); }});
    });
```

hope it helps others with the same problem.